# Python with MFCC Features to train SVM using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm, mfcc

I'm having problems particularly with numpy.
For testing purposes, I'm trying to train MFCC's of two wav files. Both of the array sizes are the same.

When I'm trying to fit the data into classifier I'm having

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Let me be more precise since I'm struggling with this numpy shape problem with myself for long time and couldn't find a solution.

```
>mfccsorry = sf.getFeatures(dir+"sorry.mp3.wav")
>mfccsorry.shape
(622, 13)
>mfccsorry = sf.getFeatures(dir+"sorry.mp3.wav")
(622, 13)
>mfcctestwav = sf.getFeatures(dir+"test.mp3.wav")
(622, 13)
>arr = [mfccsorry,mfccsad]
>targ = ["sad","hope"]
```

At this point, I'm trying to label the feature vector one with "sad" and the second with "hope" and hoping to predict the label of mfcctestwav.

```
clf.fit(arr, targ)
```

Returns the error.

I've tried to ravel the arrays and that resulted with 0.5,0.5 prediction rate, which was not a surprise since I've merged all the feature vectors into one.
I believe I'm having a problem regarding to Numpy's or ,in general, SVM matrix formations.

I've checked the documentation from
http://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

But still couldn't find the problem myself.
Thanks for all sorts of suggestions and explanations.

EDIT:
I know that the line

```
>arr = [mfccsorry,mfccsad]
```

creates an 3D array with shape (2, 622, 13) which ultimately causes the error. Should I reshape it to 2D array, if so what should be the correct form and what might be the logic behind it.

Comment: first of all, you will not be ever able to use (obtain anything reasonable with) SVM with **a single observation per class**

Comment: The sklearn method `clf.fit()` takes an array with `shape == (num_samples, num_features)` as input (i.e. a 2D array).

Comment: The sklearn method `clf.fit()` takes an array with `shape == (num_samples, num_features)` as input (i.e. a 2-D array). To get this you will need to flatten and stack your feature arrays (i.e. `mfccsorry` & `mfcctestwav`), e.g. like this: `arr = np.r_[mfccsorry, mfcctestwav]`. `Targ` needs to be an numerical array where the labels are coded by numbers (e.g. `Targ = np.array([0., 1.])`, "sad" -> 0 & "hope" -> 1). Also, `arr = [mfccsorry,mfccsad]` shouldn't yield an array, but a list of arrays. Finally, as @lejlot pointed out, there is not learning to be done from 1 observation per class.